# spire.doc can not convert data from doc/rtf file to pdf

Tags: spire.doc

I am using spire.office. It is converting data from excel to pdf successfully but not from the document or RTF file. It is showing the following error 
Could not load type 'spr᝚' from assembly 'Spire.Doc, Version=7.1.13.41046, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3' because it attempts to implement a class as an interface.

Please check it and gives some advice. Thanks in advance

```
File.WriteAllText(filepath + ".rtf", fileText);
                Document doc = new Document(filepath + ".docx", Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
                //doc.LoadFromFile(filepath + ".docx",Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
                doc.SaveToFile(filepath + ".pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

When converting files to PDF, you also need to add **Spire.Pdf.dll**. If not, it might throw that kind of "spr" error. Additionally, you should specify the FileFormat as PDF: `doc.SaveToFile(filepath + ".pdf", FileFormat.PDF);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you load license beforehand?

```
Spire.License.LicenseProvider.SetLicenseFileName("license.elic.xml");
Spire.License.LicenseProvider.LoadLicense();
```